# Related products in the addtocart.phtml?

Tags: product, layout

I need to move the related products to

below the product options 
and above the add to cart button

Is there a way to call the related products from within addtocart.phtml?

I tried moving the following out of view.phtml into addtocart.phtml but nothing shows

```
 if ($tmpHtml = trim($this->getChildHtml('catalog.product.related')))
     echo '<div class="box-sidebar-inner">'. $tmpHtml .'</div>';
```

Can anyone help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your layout file **catalog.xml**:

**Was**:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
```

**Should be:**

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml">
        <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
</block>
```

Your code should work then.

In case you have getChildHtml('') block you should create block in addtocart.phtml template:

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>

<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list_related')->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/related.phtml')->toHtml() ?>

<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <div class="add-to-cart">
        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
        <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: That kind of works.. But the related products show underneath when i add the XML, then when i add the code in they show in the right place. But stay underneath also.. So there are 2 copies

Comment: Why don't use 2 items of block? You could rename it under the addtocart node.

Comment: What i mean is the related products are showing up twice now with this method... I only want them to show once

They are displaying underneath the addtocart section with the XML, then being duplicated when i add the code into addtocart.phtml.. How do i remove the ones from showing below

Comment: Ah, I see now. I updated my post.

Comment: Thats great - I get how it works now.. Thanks a lot